# How do i get the value of my used defined conditions so i can set the stop loss value?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My code sets entry conditions based on crossover of a plotted line which is Ok, I have alos coded to plot another line for the stop loss (the value of which is dependant on the my 'dist' variable) and defined a condition when this is true however when i try to input a stop loss with this condition the oder requires a 'float' value and my confition only generates a bool.
how can i get the 'float value / price' for when the condition occurs so i can set the stop loss?
I've tried 'valuewhen' but this doesnt seem to work!

Ultimately I am trying to achieve the follwoing logic
If BullFVG
set limit order at bullentrycross
set stop loss at bullstoploss
set take profit at RR 3:1 (3 times the distance of order - stoploss

Can you help please?

Code is

```
`//@version=5
strategy("My FVG Detector - Helped"
  , overlay = true
  , max_boxes_count = 500
  , max_labels_count = 500
  , max_lines_count = 500
  , pyramiding = 100
  , calc_on_every_tick = true)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Fair Value Gaps
show_fvg = input(true, 'Fair Value Gaps (FVG)'
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_fvg_css = input.color(#2157f3, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bear_fvg_css = input.color(#ff1100, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_usewidth = input(true, 'Min Width'
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_gapwidth = input.float(1.95, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_method = input.string('ATR', ''
  , options = ['Points', '%', 'ATR']
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_extend = input.int(3, 'Extend FVG'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bear_entry = input.int(80, 'Bear Entry Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bear_exit = input.int(80, 'Bear Stop Loss Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_entry = input.int(80, 'Bull Entry Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_exit = input.int(80, 'Bull Stop Loss Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

adboxcount = input.int (50, "Maximum Imb Displayed", 1, group = "Chart Customization")

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{

n = bar_index
atr = ta.atr(200)

//Detect imbalance and return count over time
imbalance_detection(show, usewidth, method, width, top, btm, condition, wide)=>
    var is_width = true
    var count = 0
    
    if usewidth
        dist = top - btm
        bull_wide = top - btm

        is_width := switch method
            'Points' => dist > width
            '%' => dist / btm * 100 > width
            'ATR' => dist > atr * width

    is_true = show and condition and is_width
    count += is_true ? 1 : 0
    
    [is_true, count]
  

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Arrays
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{

var box[] bearimbboxarray = array.new_box()
var box[] bearfvgboxarray = array.new_box()
var line[] bear_avg_line = array.new_line()
var line[] bear_boxlow = array.new_line()
var line[] bear_boxhigh = array.new_line()

var box[] bullimbboxarray = array.new_box()
var box[] bullfvgboxarray = array.new_box()
var line[] bull_avg_line = array.new_line()
var line[] bull_boxlow = array.new_line()
var line[] bull_boxhigh = array.new_line()


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Fair Value Gaps
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Bullish
[bull_fvg, bull_fvg_count] = imbalance_detection(
  show_fvg
  , fvg_usewidth
  , fvg_method
  , fvg_gapwidth
  , low
  , high[2]
  , low > high[2] and close[1] > high[2]
  , high[2] - low)
bull_top = bull_fvg
bull_width = low - high[2]
bull_avg = math.avg(high[2], low)

// Calculate the distance between the midpoint and the high
bull_exit_dist = (high[2] - bull_avg) * (100 - bull_exit) / 100
// Calculate the new high value
bull_exit_line = high[2] - bull_exit_dist

// Calculate the distance between the midpoint and the low
bull_entry_dist = (low - bull_avg) * (100 - bull_entry) / 100
    // Calculate the new low value
bull_entry_line = low - bull_entry_dist

//Bearish
[bear_fvg, bear_fvg_count] = imbalance_detection(
  show_fvg
  , fvg_usewidth
  , fvg_method
  , fvg_gapwidth
  , low[2]
  , high
  , high < low[2] and close[1] < low[2]
  , low[2] - high)
bear_top = bear_fvg
bear_width = low[2] - high
bear_avg = math.avg(low[2], high)

// Calculate the distance between the midpoint and the high
bear_entry_dist = (high - bear_avg) * (100 - bear_entry) / 100
// Calculate the new high value
bear_entry_line = high - bear_entry_dist

// Calculate the distance between the midpoint and the low
bear_exit_dist = (low[2] - bear_avg) * (100 - bear_exit) / 100
    // Calculate the new low value
bear_exit_line = low[2] - bear_exit_dist
 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//BOX AND ARRAY CALCULATIONS
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{

///// BULLS /////

// Box & Line Calc {
b_choppedoffimb(bullimbboxarray, bull_avg_line, bull_boxlow, bull_boxhigh) =>
    if array.size(bullimbboxarray) > 0 and array.size(bull_avg_line) > 0 and array.size(bull_boxlow) > 0 and array.size(bull_boxhigh) > 0
        for i = array.size(bullimbboxarray) - 1 to 0 by 1
            bullcutbox = array.get(bullimbboxarray, i)
            bullcutline = array.get(bull_avg_line, i)
            bullboxhighzone = box.get_top(bullcutbox)
            bullboxlowzone = box.get_bottom(bullcutbox)
            bullboxrightzone = box.get_right(bullcutbox)
            if na or bar_index - 1 == bullboxrightzone and not (open < bullboxhighzone)
                box.set_right(array.get(bullimbboxarray, i), bar_index)
                line.set_x2(array.get(bull_avg_line, i), bar_index)
                line.set_x2(array.get(bull_boxlow, i), bar_index)
                line.set_x2(array.get(bull_boxhigh, i), bar_index)

// }

// SET VARIABLE VALUES TO 0
var bullboxhighzone = 0.
var bullboxlowzone = 0.
var bullentry = 0.
var bullexit = 0.
var bullfgvextent = 0.

// RESET VARIABLE VALUES
bullboxhighzone := bull_top and bull_width > 0 ? low : bullboxhighzone
bullboxlowzone := bull_top and bull_width > 0 ? high[2] : bullboxlowzone
bullentry := bull_top and bull_width > 0 ? bull_entry_line : bullentry
bullexit := bull_top and bull_width > 0 ? bull_exit_line : bullexit
bullfgvextent := bull_top and bull_width > 0 ? bull_exit_line : bullfgvextent

// SETS CONDITION FOR WHEN FVG BOX IS PLOTTED
var bullbelowBoxhighzone = false
var bullbelowentryzone = false
if bullimbboxarray.size() > 0
    bullbelowBoxhighzone := (high[2] < box.get_top(bullimbboxarray.last())) ? false : bullbelowBoxhighzone

//var bullbelowBoxhighzone = false
//var bullbelowentryzone = false
//if array.size(bullimbboxarray) > 0
//    for i = array.size(bullimbboxarray) - 1 to 0 by 1
//        bulllastBox2 = array.get(bullimbboxarray, i)
//        bullleft = box.get_left(bulllastBox2)
//        bullright = box.get_right(bulllastBox2)
//        if bar_index >= bullleft and bar_index <= bullright
//            bullbelowBoxhighzone := true
//            break
//        else
//            bullbelowBoxhighzone := false

// SETS CONDITION FOR WHEN FGV_EXTEND BOX IS PLOTTED
var bullbelowFVGBoxhighzone = false
var bullbelowFVGentryzone = false
if array.size(bullfvgboxarray) > 0
    for i = array.size(bullfvgboxarray) - 1 to 0 by 1
        bulllastBox = array.get(bullfvgboxarray, i)
        bullleft = box.get_left(bulllastBox)
        bullright = box.get_right(bulllastBox)
        if bar_index >= bullleft and bar_index <= bullright
            bullbelowFVGBoxhighzone := true
            break
        else
            bullbelowFVGBoxhighzone := false

b_choppedoffimb(bullimbboxarray, bull_avg_line, bull_boxlow, bull_boxhigh)

///// BEARS /////

// Box & Line Calc {
f_choppedoffimb(bearimbboxarray, bear_avg_line, bear_boxlow, bear_boxhigh) =>
    if array.size(bearimbboxarray) > 0 and array.size(bear_avg_line) > 0 and array.size(bear_boxlow) > 0 and array.size(bear_boxhigh) > 0
        for i = array.size(bearimbboxarray) - 1 to 0 by 1
            bearcutbox = array.get(bearimbboxarray, i)
            bearcutline = array.get(bear_avg_line, i)
            bearboxhighzone = box.get_top(bearcutbox)
            bearboxlowzone = box.get_bottom(bearcutbox)
            bearboxrightzone = box.get_right(bearcutbox)
            if na or bar_index - 1 == bearboxrightzone and not (open > bearboxlowzone)
                box.set_right(array.get(bearimbboxarray, i), bar_index)
                line.set_x2(array.get(bear_avg_line, i), bar_index)
                line.set_x2(array.get(bear_boxlow, i), bar_index)
                line.set_x2(array.get(bear_boxhigh, i), bar_index)

// }

// SET VARIABLE VALUES TO 0
var bearboxhighzone = 0.
var bearboxlowzone = 0.
var bearentry = 0.
var bearexit = 0.
var bearfgvextent = 0.

// RESET VARIABLE VALUES
bearboxhighzone := bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? low[2] : bearboxhighzone
bearboxlowzone := bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? high[0] : bearboxlowzone
bearentry := bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? bear_entry_line : bearentry
bearexit := bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? bear_exit_line : bearexit
bearfgvextent := bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? bear_exit_line : bearfgvextent

// SETS CONDITION FOR WHEN FVG BOX IS PLOTTED
var bearbelowBoxhighzone = false
var bearbelowentryzone = false
if bearimbboxarray.size() > 0
    bearbelowBoxhighzone := (high > box.get_top(bearimbboxarray.last())) ? false : bearbelowBoxhighzone

// SETS CONDITION FOR WHEN FGV_EXTEND BOX IS PLOTTED
var bearbelowFVGBoxhighzone = false
var bearbelowFVGentryzone = false
if array.size(bearfvgboxarray) > 0
    for i = array.size(bearfvgboxarray) - 1 to 0 by 1
        bearlastBox = array.get(bearfvgboxarray, i)
        bearleft = box.get_left(bearlastBox)
        bearright = box.get_right(bearlastBox)
        if bar_index >= bearleft and bar_index <= bearright
            bearbelowFVGBoxhighzone := true
            break
        else
            bearbelowFVGBoxhighzone := false

f_choppedoffimb(bearimbboxarray, bear_avg_line, bear_boxlow, bear_boxhigh)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//ALERT CONDITIONS
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{

// SET CONDTIONS FOR LABELS / ALERTS
// ENTRY CONDITIONS
///// BULLS /////

// ENTRY//
//bullentrycross = ta.crossover(low, bullentry) and bullbelowFVGBoxhighzone
bullentrycross = close < bullentry and bullbelowFVGBoxhighzone
if bullentrycross
    label.new(bar_index, bull_avg, "bull Entry", xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = color.blue, style = label.style_arrowup, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)

// STOP LOSS //
bullstoploss = bullentrycross and bull_exit_line
if bullstoploss
    label.new(bar_index, bullboxhighzone + 100, "Stop Loss", xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.price, color = color.blue, style = label.style_flag, textcolor = color.rgb(27, 25, 25), size = size.tiny)
bullstoplossprice = ta.valuewhen(bullstoploss, close, 0)




//crossoverHighBoxLowZone =  ta.crossover(open, bearboxlowzone) and bearbelowBoxhighzone
//bearentrycross = ta.crossover(high, bearentry) and bearbelowBoxhighzone

///// BEARS /////

// ENTRY //
bearentrycross = ta.crossover(high, bearentry) and bearbelowFVGBoxhighzone
//bearentrycross = open > bearentry and open[1] < bearentry and bearbelowFVGBoxhighzone
if bearentrycross
    label.new(bar_index, bear_avg, "Bear Entry", xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = color.red, style = label.style_arrowdown, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)

// STOP LOSS CONDITION //
//bearstoploss = bearentrycross and bear_exit_line
//if bearstoploss
//    label.new(bar_index, bear_exit_line + 0.5, "Stop Loss", xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.price, color = color.red, style = label.style_flag, textcolor = color.rgb(27, 25, 25), size = size.tiny)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//CHART PLOTTING
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{

///// BULLS /////
// DRAW BOXES AND LINES
// Box Draw {
if bull_top and bull_width > 0
    bullimbbox = box.new(bar_index, bullboxhighzone, bar_index, bullboxlowzone, bull_fvg_css, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bull_fvg_css, 80))
    bullmidline = line.new(bar_index, bull_avg, bar_index, bull_avg, color = color.blue, style = line.style_solid)
    bullentryline = line.new(bar_index, bull_entry_line, bar_index, bull_entry_line, color = color.purple, style = line.style_dashed)
    bullexitline = line.new(bar_index, bull_exit_line, bar_index, bull_exit_line, color = color.blue, style = line.style_dashed)
    bullfgvline = box.new(bar_index, bull_entry_line, bar_index + fvg_extend, bull_exit_line, border_color = color.rgb(155, 39, 176, 89), border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bull_fvg_css, 80))

    if array.size(bullimbboxarray) > adboxcount
        box.delete(array.shift(bullimbboxarray))
        line.delete(array.shift(bull_avg_line))
        line.delete(array.shift(bull_boxlow))
        line.delete(array.shift(bull_boxhigh))
    array.push(bullimbboxarray, bullimbbox)
    array.push(bull_avg_line, bullmidline)
    array.push(bull_boxlow, bullentryline)
    array.push(bull_boxhigh, bullexitline)
    array.push(bullfvgboxarray, bullfgvline)
    bullbelowBoxhighzone := true
    bullbelowFVGBoxhighzone := true

///// BEARS /////
// DRAW BOXES AND LINES
// Box Draw {
if bear_top and bear_width > 0
    bearimbbox = box.new(bar_index, bearboxhighzone, bar_index, bearboxlowzone, bear_fvg_css, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bear_fvg_css, 80))
    bearmidline = line.new(bar_index, bear_avg, bar_index, bear_avg, color = color.red, style = line.style_solid)
    bearentryline = line.new(bar_index, bear_entry_line, bar_index, bear_entry_line, color = color.purple, style = line.style_dashed)
    bearexitline = line.new(bar_index, bear_exit_line, bar_index, bear_exit_line, color = color.blue, style = line.style_dashed)
    bearfgvline = box.new(bar_index, bear_exit_line, bar_index + fvg_extend, bear_entry_line, border_color = color.purple, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bear_fvg_css, 80))

    if array.size(bearimbboxarray) > adboxcount
        box.delete(array.shift(bearimbboxarray))
        line.delete(array.shift(bear_avg_line))
        line.delete(array.shift(bear_boxlow))
        line.delete(array.shift(bear_boxhigh))
    array.push(bearimbboxarray, bearimbbox)
    array.push(bear_avg_line, bearmidline)
    array.push(bear_boxlow, bearentryline)
    array.push(bear_boxhigh, bearexitline)
    array.push(bearfvgboxarray, bearfgvline)
    bearbelowBoxhighzone := true
    bearbelowFVGBoxhighzone := true

// SET CANDLE COLORS
barcolor(bearentrycross ? color.yellow : na)
barcolor(bullentrycross ? color.yellow : na)


// ENTRIES AND EXITS
`
```

I've tried the below, but the stoploss needs to be a float value, not a bool and i dont know how to get the value?  please help

//LONG
//AIM
//when bull FVG is identified. place limit buy order 'entry' threshold, place stop loss at FVG bottom and set profit take at 3 x RR ratio

```
if bullentrycross and strategy.position_size <= 0
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)

// Set stop loss order
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long", stop=bullstoplossprice)

// Set take profit order at 3:1 ratio
profit_target = strategy.position_avg_price + (strategy.position_avg_price - bullstoplossprice) * 3
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Long", limit=profit_target)
```

Answer (score 0):

option 1

```
var float bullstoplossprice = na

if bullentrycross and strategy.position_size <= 0
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    bullstoplossprice := close

// Set stop loss order
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long", stop=bullstoplossprice)
```

Option 2

```
if bullentrycross and strategy.position_size <= 0
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    // Set stop loss order
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long", stop = close)
```